# Handler для чтения сообщений через Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-handler

Доброго времени суток! Пишу приложение, в котором происходит связь между устройством и смартфоном посредством bluetooth, а именно, я отправляю устройству команду, оно в ответ присылает мне строку данных, которую необходимо разобрать. Прием сообщений осуществляется с помощью *Handler*. 
Проблема состоит в том, что в приложении у меня несколько активностей, и при смене активности команда отправляется, но устройство её не получает.
Помогите разобраться в проблеме.
Я полагаю, что при смене активностей *bluetooth socket* разрывается, поэтому устройство не получает от меня команду. 
И ещё одна проблема состоит в том, сколько необходимо *Handler*? Для каждой активности свой, или один для всех?

*Bluetooth Service*

```
public class BluetoothService extends Service {

public BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = null;
BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
public static final String SPP_UUID = "00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB";
//public static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
private ConnectThread mConnectThread;
private ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;
private static Handler mHandler = new MainActivity.mHandler();
public static int mState = Constants.STATE_NONE;
StringBuilder sb;
public static int TypeMessage;


@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG, "***Service started***");
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG, "***Binding***");
    //mHandler = ((MyApplication) getApplication()).getHandler();
    return mBinder;
}

public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    BluetoothService getService() {
        return BluetoothService.this;
    }
}


private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG, "***OnStart Command***");
    bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    if (bluetoothAdapter != null) {
        String MACaddr = intent.getStringExtra("mac");
        Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG, MACaddr);
        if (MACaddr != null && MACaddr.length() > 0) {
            connectToDevice(MACaddr);
        } else {
            stopSelf();
            return START_STICKY_COMPATIBILITY;
        }
    }
    return START_STICKY;
}

/*final BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            deviceName = device.getName();
            MAC = device.getAddress();
            Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(MainActivity.MESSAGE_DEVICE);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("name", deviceName);
            bundle.putString("mac", MAC);
            msg.setData(bundle);
            mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
            Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG, deviceName + MAC);
        }
    }
};*/

private synchronized void connectToDevice(String MACaddr) {
    BluetoothDevice device = bluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(MACaddr);
    Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG, "***Получили удаленный Device***" + device.getName());
    if (mState == Constants.STATE_CONNECTING) {
        if (mConnectThread != null) {
            mConnectThread.cancel();
            mConnectThread = null;
        }
    }

    // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
    if (mConnectedThread != null) {
        mConnectedThread.cancel();
        mConnectedThread = null;
    }
    mConnectThread = new ConnectThread(device);
    mConnectThread.start();
    Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG, "***Соединение с " + device.getName() + " успешно установлено***");
    setState(Constants.STATE_CONNECTING);
}

/*public synchronized void connectToDevice(String MAC) {
    BluetoothDevice device = bluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(MAC);
    Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG, "***Получили удаленный Device***" + device.getName());
    try {
        bluetoothSocket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
        Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG, "...Создали сокет...");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        MyError("Fatal Error", "В onResume() Не могу создать сокет: " + e.getMessage() + ".");
    }

    bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
    Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG, "***Отменили поиск других устройств***");

    Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG, "***Соединяемся...***");
    try {
        bluetoothSocket.connect();
        Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG, "***Соединение успешно установлено***");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        try {
            bluetoothSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e2) {
            MyError("Fatal Error", "В onResume() не могу закрыть сокет" + e2.getMessage() + ".");
        }
    }
    mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(bluetoothSocket);
    mConnectedThread.start();
    TypeMessage = Constants.GET_GROUP_INFO;
    mConnectedThread.sendData("[GET_GROUP_INFO]");
    //setState(Constants.STATE_CONNECTING);
}

private void MyError(String title, String message){
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), title + " - " + message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    stopSelf();
}*/

private void setState(int state) {
    BluetoothService.mState = state;
    if (mHandler != null) {
        mHandler.obtainMessage(MainActivity.MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE, state, -1).sendToTarget();
    }
}

public synchronized void stop() {
    setState(Constants.STATE_NONE);

    if (mConnectedThread != null) {
        mConnectedThread.cancel();
        mConnectedThread = null;
    }
    if (bluetoothAdapter != null) {
        bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
    }
    stopSelf();
}

@Override
public boolean stopService(Intent name) {
    setState(Constants.STATE_NONE);
    if (mConnectThread != null) {
        mConnectThread.cancel();
        mConnectThread = null;
    }

    if (mConnectedThread != null) {
        mConnectedThread.cancel();
        mConnectedThread = null;
    }

    bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
    return super.stopService(name);
}

private void connectionFailed() {
    BluetoothService.this.stop();
    Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(MainActivity.MESSAGE_TOAST);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(Constants.TOAST, getString(R.string.error_connect_failed));
    msg.setData(bundle);
    mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
}

private void connectionLost() {
    BluetoothService.this.stop();
    Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(MainActivity.MESSAGE_TOAST);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(Constants.TOAST, getString(R.string.error_connect_lost));
    msg.setData(bundle);
    mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
}

private static Object obj = new Object();

private synchronized void connected(BluetoothSocket mmSocket, BluetoothDevice mmDevice) {
    // Cancel the thread that completed the connection
    if (mConnectThread != null) {
        mConnectThread.cancel();
        mConnectThread = null;
    }

    // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
    if (mConnectedThread != null) {
        mConnectedThread.cancel();
        mConnectedThread = null;
    }

    mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(mmSocket);
    mConnectedThread.start();
    setState(Constants.STATE_CONNECTED);

}

private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;

    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
        this.mmDevice = device;
        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
        try {
            tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.fromString(SPP_UUID));
            Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG, "...Создали сокет...");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mmSocket = tmp;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        setName("ConnectThread");
        bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG, "***Отменили поиск других устройств***");
        try {
            mmSocket.connect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            connectionFailed();
            return;

        }
        synchronized (BluetoothService.this) {
            mConnectThread = null;
        }
        connected(mmSocket, mmDevice);

    }

    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(Constants.LOG_TAG, "***close() of connect socket failed***", e);
        }
    }
}

private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {

    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final InputStream mmInStream;
    private final OutputStream mmOutStream;
    private byte[] buffer;

    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
        mmSocket = socket;
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;
        try {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(Constants.LOG_TAG, "***temp sockets not created***", e);
        }
        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytes;

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        while (true) {
            try {
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                String message = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
                sb.append(message);

                handler.obtainMessage(0, buffer.length, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();
                sb.setLength(0);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                BluetoothService.this.stop();
                break;
            }

        }
    }


    public void sendData(String message) {
        byte[] msgBuffer = message.getBytes();
        Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG, "***Отправляем данные: " + message + "***" );
        try {
            mmOutStream.write(msgBuffer);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(Constants.LOG_TAG, "***Exception during write***", e);
        }
    }

    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(Constants.LOG_TAG, "***close() of connect socket failed***", e);
        }
    }

}

public void trace(String msg) {
    Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG, msg);
    toast(msg);
}

public void toast(String msg) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    stop();
    Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG, "***Service Destroyed***");
    //unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
    //Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG, "***Receiver unregistered***");
    super.onDestroy();
}

private void sendMsg(int flag) {
    Message msg = new Message();
    msg.what = flag;
    handler.sendMessage(msg);
}

private Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {//
        if (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            switch (TypeMessage) {
                case Constants.GET_GROUP_INFO:
                    break;
                case Constants.DATETIME_setD:
                    break;
                case Constants.DATETIME:
                    break;
            }
        }
        super.handleMessage(msg);
    }

};
```

*MainActivity*

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public static final int MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE = 1;
public static final int MESSAGE_TOAST = 2;
public static final int MESSAGE_WRITE = 3;
public static final int MESSAGE_DEVICE = 4;
public static final int MESSAGE_ANSWER = 5;

BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
BluetoothService btService;
boolean mBound = false;
static ArrayAdapter<String> btArrayAdapter;
BluetoothDevice device;
private  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
public  static TextView  text, status, impWeight, curValueMeter, curDate, addressAPN,
        loginAPN, passAPN, URL, num1, num2, comSessMode,
        curSupVoltage, curBBVoltage, imei, levelGSM, repDate, backupInterval,
        maxSession, meterSinceFirst, meterFail, curRecInArch, meterType, meterSerNumber;
Button synchr;
ListView listView;
static ProgressBar pb;
Context context;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    status = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    impWeight = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    curValueMeter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    curDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    addressAPN = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    loginAPN = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);
    passAPN = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7);
    URL = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView8);
    num1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView9);
    num2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView10);
    comSessMode = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView11);
    curSupVoltage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView12);
    curBBVoltage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView13);
    imei = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView14);
    levelGSM = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView15);
    repDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView16);
    backupInterval = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView17);
    maxSession = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView18);
    meterSinceFirst = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView19);
    meterFail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView20);
    curRecInArch = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView21);
    meterType = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView22);
    meterSerNumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView23);

    bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    if (bluetoothAdapter == null) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Device does not support Bluetooth", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    } else {
        if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, 1);
        }
    }

    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    pb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pb);
    synchr = (Button) findViewById(R.id.synchr);
    synchr.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yy,HH:mm:ss");
            final String d = dateFormat.format(new Date());
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, BluetoothService.class);
    bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mBound) {
        unbindService(mConnection);
        mBound = false;
    }
}

private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG, "***Service connected***");
        BluetoothService.LocalBinder binder = (BluetoothService.LocalBinder) service;
        btService = binder.getService();
        mBound = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        mBound = false;
    }
};

final BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            btArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
            btArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
};

public void search() {
    if (bluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
        bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
    } else {
        btArrayAdapter.clear();
        bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND));
    }
}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    //startService(new Intent(this, BluetoothService.class));
    //Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG, "***OnStartCommand started***");
    pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    setup();
    search();
}

private void setup() {
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    btArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    listView.setAdapter(btArrayAdapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            pb.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
            listView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            synchr.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            String itemValue = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            String MAC = itemValue.substring(itemValue.length() - 17);
            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BluetoothService.class);
            serviceIntent.putExtra("mac", MAC);
            startService(serviceIntent);
        }

    });
}



@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
    Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG, "***Receiver unregistered***");
}


public static class mHandler extends Handler {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage (android.os.Message msg){
        switch (msg.what) {
            case (MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE):
                switch (msg.arg1) {
                    case Constants.STATE_CONNECTED:
                        break;
                    case Constants.STATE_CONNECTING:
                        break;
                    case Constants.STATE_NONE:
                        break;
                    case Constants.STATE_ERROR:
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case (MESSAGE_TOAST):
                msg.getData().getString(Constants.TOAST);
                break;
            case (MESSAGE_WRITE):
                break;
            case (MESSAGE_DEVICE):
                String deviceName = msg.getData().getString("name");
                String MACAddr = msg.getData().getString("mac");
                btArrayAdapter.add(deviceName +"\n" +MACAddr);
                btArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                break;
            case (MESSAGE_ANSWER):
                String GGI = msg.getData().getString("GGI");
                String[] result = GGI.split(";");
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                    stringBuilder.append(result[i]);
                    if (i != result.length - 1) {
                        stringBuilder.append("\n");
                        status.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                        status.setText("Статус: НОРМА");
                        impWeight.setText("Вес импульса: " + result[1]);
                        curValueMeter.setText("Текущее значение счётчика: " + result[2]);
                        curDate.setText("Текущая дата: " + result[3]);
                        addressAPN.setText("Адрес APN: " + result[4]);
                        loginAPN.setText("Логин APN: " + result[5]);
                        passAPN.setText("Пароль APN: " + result[6]);
                        URL.setText("URL адрес сервера: " + result[7]);
                        num1.setText("Телефон для СМС №1: " + result[8]);
                        num2.setText("Телефон для СМС №2: " + result[9]);
                        String comsesmode = result[10];
                        String[] split = comsesmode.split(",");
                        StringBuilder sbb = new StringBuilder();
                        for (int j = 0; j < split.length; j++) {
                            sbb.append(split[j]);
                            if (j != split.length - 1) {
                                sbb.append(",");
                            }
                        }
                        int k = Integer.parseInt(split[0]);
                        if (k == 1) {
                            comSessMode.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                            comSessMode.setText("Режим сеанса связи: каждый час");
                        }
                        if (k == 2) {
                            comSessMode.setText("Режим сеанса связи: каждый день в " + split[1]);
                        }
                        if (k == 3) {
                            comSessMode.setText("Режим сеанса связи: каждую неделю в " + split[2] + " день недели в " + split[1]);
                        }
                        if (k == 4) {
                            comSessMode.setText("Режим сеанса связи: " + split[2] + " числа каждый месяц в " + split[1]);
                        }
                        curSupVoltage.setText("Текущее напряжение питания в mV: " + result[11]);
                        curBBVoltage.setText("Текущее напряжение резервной батареи в mV: " + result[12]);
                        imei.setText("IMEI модема: " + result[13]);
                        levelGSM.setText("Уровень GSM сигнала: " + result[14]);
                        repDate.setText("Отчётная дата: " + result[15]);
                        backupInterval.setText("Резервный интервал: " + result[16]);
                        maxSession.setText("Максимальное число сеансов связи: " + result[17]);
                        meterSinceFirst.setText("Счётчик числа сеансов связи с момента первого включения: " + result[18]);
                        meterFail.setText("Счётчик количества неуд. попыток связи до успешной связи: " + result[19]);
                        curRecInArch.setText("Номер текущей записи в интервальном архиве: " + result[20]);
                        meterType.setText("Тип счётчика: " + result[21]);
                        meterSerNumber.setText("Серийный номер счетчика: " + result[22]);
                    }
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Рекомендую вынести логику работы с Bluetooth в настоящий сервис Android, в котором  будет принимать команды от Activity и обработки ответов от устройства с последующей отправкой данных обратно, этим вы абстрагируетесь от низкоуровневой работы в самой активити. А если нужно чтобы при смене активити данные сохранялись нужно сделать что-то вроде паттерна Observable и оповещать сервис о готовности принимать данные, и сделать очередь данных в сервисе для отправки данных которые не приняла предыдущая активити.

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать!

Comment: Пытаюсь убрать всю логику работы с bluetooth в service и возникла проблема с осуществлением поиска устройств. Как реализовать её в service? Может есть ссылки на примеры или вы подскажете? Спасибо!

Comment: А что именно произошло, можно конкретнее?

Comment: В том то и дело, что ничего не происходит, когда я пытаюсь запустить поиск устройств не в Activity, а в Service. То есть я хочу запустить в Service поиск устройств, вывести эти устройства в ListView в Activity и по нажатию на нужном устройстве подключаться к нему. Вот как то так.

Comment: Могу предложить такое решение - в сервисе получаем список устройств, преобразуете в нужную модель для адаптера списка в активити, отправляем в интенте, отображаем, при выборе отправляем id или модель обратно, и подключаемся к девайсу. Попробуйте, если что не так код желательно приложите

Comment: Реализовала таким образом (Код в обновленном вопросе). Теперь возникает проблема с передачей сообщения, поиск и подключение выполняются. Возможно я не до конца понимаю как правильно общаться с Активность через Handler.

Comment: Делаю на основе этого примера. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15025852/how-to-move-bluetooth-activity-into-a-service

Answer (score 0):

Сделал сервис для работы с Ble, пока сырой, но работает стабильно:

```
class BluetoothService : Service(), SearchService, ConnectionService {

private val TAG = javaClass.canonicalName

companion object {
    val SERVICE_UUID = UUID.fromString("b546f776-ed87-4944-85b2-edd581cfbd97")

    val CHARACTERISTIC_1_UUID = UUID.fromString("b546f776-ed87-4944-85b2-edd581cfbd97")
    val CHARACTERISTIC_2_REGISTRATION_UUID = UUID.fromString("b546f776-ed87-4944-85b2-edd581cfbd97")
    val CHARACTERISTIC_3_UUID = UUID.fromString("b546f776-ed87-4944-85b2-edd581cfbd97")

    val CLIENT_CHARACTERISTIC_CONFIG_UUID = convertFromInteger(0x2902)

    private fun convertFromInteger(i: Int): UUID {
        val MSB = 0x0000000000001000L
        val LSB = -0x7fffff7fa064cb05L
        val value = (i and -0x1).toLong()
        return UUID(MSB or (value shl 32), LSB)
    }
}

enum class ServiceState {
    UNBIND,
    BOUND,
    IDLE,
    SCANNING
}

inner class BluetoothServiceBinder : Binder() {
    internal val searchService: BluetoothService
        get() = this@BluetoothService
}

private val binder = BluetoothServiceBinder()

private lateinit var bluetoothAdapter: BluetoothAdapter

private val devices = HashSet<BluetoothDevice>()

private var gattDevice: MutableMap<BluetoothGatt, Device> = mutableMapOf()
private var mGattListener: MutableMap<BluetoothGatt, ConnectionService.DeviceConnectionListener> = mutableMapOf()
private var mDeviceListener: MutableMap<Device, ConnectionService.AttributesActionListener> = mutableMapOf()

private var mGattNotificationListener: MutableMap<BluetoothGatt, ConnectionService.AttributesActionListener> = mutableMapOf()


private var bound: Int = 0
private var state: ServiceState = ServiceState.UNBIND

private val mListeners: MutableSet<DosimeterSearchService.ConnectionListener> = mutableSetOf()

private data class Argument(
        val action: ConnectionService.Action,
        val attribute: ConnectionService.Attribute,
        val characteristic: UUID,
        val value: Any? = null)

private val attributeArgument: MutableMap<BluetoothGatt, MutableMap<BluetoothGattCharacteristic, Argument>> = mutableMapOf()
private val attributeArgumentChanged: MutableMap<BluetoothGatt, MutableMap<BluetoothGattCharacteristic, Argument>> = mutableMapOf()


override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder? {

    bound++

    state = ServiceState.BOUND

    val bluetoothManager = getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE) as BluetoothManager
    bluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.adapter

    return binder
}

override fun onUnbind(intent: Intent): Boolean {

    if (--bound == 0) {
        state = ServiceState.UNBIND
    }

    return super.onUnbind(intent)
}

override fun startScan(scanTime: Long, listener: DosimeterSearchService.ConnectionListener) {

    devices.clear()
    mListeners.add(listener)

    if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled) {
        listener.onEnableBluetoothRequest(this)
    } else {
        devices.clear()

        Handler().postDelayed({
            stopScan()
        }, scanTime)

        bluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(arrayOf(SERVICE_UUID), mLeScanCallback)

        listener.onScanStarted(this)
    }
}

private val mLeScanCallback = BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback { device, rssi, scanRecord ->
    if (devices.add(device)) {
        mListeners.forEach {
            it.onDeviceFound(this)
        }
    }
}

override fun stopScan() {
    bluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback)
    mListeners.forEach {
        it.onScanStopped(this)
    }
}

override fun getFoundDevices(): List<Device> {
    return devices.map { Device(it) }
}

override fun connect(device: Device, autoConnect: Boolean, connectionListener: ConnectionService.DeviceConnectionListener) {
    if (state != ServiceState.SCANNING) {
        val gatt = device.device.connectGatt(this, autoConnect, mGattCallback)
        gattDevice[gatt] = device
        mGattListener[gatt] = connectionListener
    } else {

    }
}

override fun disconnect(device: Device) {
    if (device.connectionState == Device.ConnectionState.DISCOVERED) {
        if (gattDevice.containsValue(device)) {
            gattDevice
                    .filter { it.value == device }
                    .forEach {
                        it.key.disconnect()
                        it.key.close()
                    }
        }
    }
}

private val mGattCallback = object : BluetoothGattCallback() {

    override fun onConnectionStateChange(gatt: BluetoothGatt?, status: Int, newState: Int) {
        when (newState) {
            BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED -> {
                gattDevice[gatt]?.connectionState = Device.ConnectionState.CONNECTED
                mGattListener[gatt]?.onConnected(this@BluetoothService, gattDevice[gatt]!!)
                gatt?.discoverServices()
            }
            BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED -> {
                gattDevice[gatt]?.connectionState = Device.ConnectionState.DISCONNECTED
                mGattListener[gatt]?.onDisconnect(this@BluetoothService, gattDevice[gatt]!!)


                mDeviceListener.remove(gattDevice[gatt])
                gattDevice.remove(gatt)
                mGattListener.remove(gatt)

                mGattNotificationListener.remove(gatt)

                attributeArgument.remove(gatt)
                attributeArgumentChanged.remove(gatt)

                gatt?.disconnect()
                gatt?.close()
            }
        }

        state = ServiceState.IDLE
    }

    override fun onServicesDiscovered(gatt: BluetoothGatt?, status: Int) {
        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            gattDevice[gatt]?.connectionState = Device.ConnectionState.DISCOVERED
            mGattListener[gatt]?.onDiscovered(this@BluetoothService, gattDevice[gatt]!!)
        } else {

        }
    }

    override fun onCharacteristicRead(gatt: BluetoothGatt?, characteristic: BluetoothGattCharacteristic?, status: Int) {
        val attribute = attributeArgument[gatt]!![characteristic]!!
        attributeArgument[gatt]!!.remove(characteristic)
        mDeviceListener[gattDevice[gatt]]?.onAttributeAction(this@BluetoothService, gattDevice[gatt]!!, attribute.action, attribute.attribute, characteristic?.value)
    }

    override fun onCharacteristicWrite(gatt: BluetoothGatt?, characteristic: BluetoothGattCharacteristic?, status: Int) {
        val attribute = attributeArgument[gatt]!![characteristic]!!
        attributeArgument[gatt]!!.remove(characteristic)
        mDeviceListener[gattDevice[gatt]]?.onAttributeAction(this@BluetoothService, gattDevice[gatt]!!, attribute.action, attribute.attribute, characteristic?.value)
    }


    override fun onCharacteristicChanged(gatt: BluetoothGatt?, characteristic: BluetoothGattCharacteristic?) {
        val attribute = attributeArgumentChanged[gatt]!![characteristic]!!
        mDeviceListener[gattDevice[gatt]]?.onAttributeAction(this@BluetoothService, gattDevice[gatt]!!, attribute.action, attribute.attribute, characteristic?.value)
    }
}

override fun attribute(device: Device, attribute: ConnectionService.Attribute, action: ConnectionService.Action, attributesActionListener: ConnectionService.AttributesActionListener, value: Any?) {
    if (device.connectionState == Device.ConnectionState.DISCOVERED) {
        if (gattDevice.containsValue(device)) {

            mDeviceListener[device] = attributesActionListener

            gattDevice.entries
                    .filter { it.value == device }
                    .forEach {

                        val uuid: UUID = when (attribute) {
                            ConnectionService.Attribute.SAMPLING -> {
                                CHARACTERISTIC_1_UUID
                            }
                            ConnectionService.Attribute.PARTICLE_REGISTRATION -> {
                                CHARACTERISTIC_2_REGISTRATION_UUID
                            }
                            ConnectionService.Attribute.DOZE -> {
                                CHARACTERISTIC_3_UUID
                            }
                        }

                        val gatt = it.key
                        val characteristic = gatt.getService(SERVICE_UUID).getCharacteristic(uuid)

                        when (action) {
                            ConnectionService.Action.READ -> {
                                if (attributeArgument[gatt] == null) {
                                    attributeArgument[gatt] = mutableMapOf()
                                }
                                attributeArgument[gatt]!![characteristic] = Argument(action, attribute, uuid)

                                gatt.readCharacteristic(characteristic)
                            }
                            ConnectionService.Action.WRITE -> {
                                if (attributeArgument[gatt] == null) {
                                    attributeArgument[gatt] = mutableMapOf()
                                }
                                attributeArgument[gatt]!![characteristic] = Argument(action, attribute, uuid, value)

                                characteristic.value = value as ByteArray
                                gatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristic)
                            }
                            ConnectionService.Action.NOTIFICATION -> {
                                if (attributeArgumentChanged[gatt] == null) {
                                    attributeArgumentChanged[gatt] = mutableMapOf()
                                }
                                attributeArgumentChanged[gatt]!![characteristic] = Argument(action, attribute, uuid)

                                gatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, value as Boolean)
                                val particleRegistrationDescriptor = characteristic?.getDescriptor(CLIENT_CHARACTERISTIC_CONFIG_UUID)
                                if (particleRegistrationDescriptor?.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE)!!) {
                                    gatt.writeDescriptor(particleRegistrationDescriptor)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
        }
    }
}}
```

SearchService:

```
interface SearchService {

interface ConnectionListener {

    fun onEnableBluetoothRequest(search: SearchService)

    fun onScanStarted(search: SearchService)

    fun onScanStopped(search: SearchService)

    fun onDeviceFound(search: SearchService)
}

fun startScan(scanTime: Long, listener: ConnectionListener)

fun stopScan()

fun getFoundDevices(): List<Device>}
```

ConnectionService:

```
interface ConnectionService {

enum class Action {
    READ,
    WRITE,
    NOTIFICATION
}

enum class Attribute {
    BOOLEAN_TYPE {
        override fun <T> value(value: Any?): T {
            return ((value as ByteArray)[0].toInt() == 1) as T
        }
    },
    NOTIFICATION_TYPE {
        override fun <T> value(value: Any?): T {
            return 0 as T
        }
    },
    LONG_TYPE {
        override fun <T> value(value: Any?): T {
            val byte = value as ByteArray
            return unsignedBytesToInt(byte[0], byte[1], byte[2], byte[3])
                    as T
        }
    };

    abstract fun <T> value(value: Any?): T

    protected fun unsignedBytesToInt(b0: Byte, b1: Byte, b2: Byte, b3: Byte): Int {
        return (unsignedByteToInt(b0) + (unsignedByteToInt(b1) shl 8)
                + (unsignedByteToInt(b2) shl 16) + (unsignedByteToInt(b3) shl 24))
    }

    private fun unsignedByteToInt(b: Byte): Int {
        return b.toInt() and 0xFF
    }
}

interface AttributesActionListener {
    fun onAttributeAction(searchService: SearchService, device: Device, action: Action, attribute: Attribute, value: Any? = null)
}

interface DeviceConnectionListener {

    fun onConnected(service: ConnectionService, device: Device)

    fun onDiscovered(service: ConnectionService, device: Device)

    fun onDisconnect(service: ConnectionService, device: Device)

}

fun connect(device: Device, autoConnect: Boolean, connectionListener: DeviceConnectionListener)

fun disconnect(device: Device)

fun attribute(device: Device, attribute: Attribute, action: Action, attributesActionListener: AttributesActionListener, value: Any? = null)}
```

Device:

```
data class Device(val device: BluetoothDevice) : Parcelable {

enum class ConnectionState {
    DISCONNECTED,
    SCAN,
    CONNECTED,
    DISCOVERED
}

var connectionState: ConnectionState = ConnectionState.DISCONNECTED


constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this(parcel.readParcelable(BluetoothDevice::class.java.classLoader) as BluetoothDevice)

fun getName(): String {
    return device.name
}

fun getAddress(): String {
    return device.address
}

override fun writeToParcel(parcel: Parcel, flags: Int) {
    parcel.writeParcelable(device, flags)
}

override fun describeContents(): Int {
    return 0
}

companion object CREATOR : Parcelable.Creator<Device> {
    override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel): Device {
        return Device(parcel)
    }

    override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<Device?> {
        return arrayOfNulls(size)
    }
}}
```

Использовать так:

```
var mSearchService: BluetoothService? = null
var mDevice: Device? = null

private val mConnection = object : ServiceConnection {

    override fun onServiceConnected(className: ComponentName, service: IBinder) {
        val binder = service as BluetoothService.BluetoothServiceBinder
        mSearchService= binder.searchService
    }

    override fun onServiceDisconnected(arg0: ComponentName) {
        mSearchService = null
    }}

    override fun onStart() {
    val bluetooth = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    val bluetoothAdmin = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    val gps = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED

    if (bluetooth && bluetoothAdmin && gps) {
        val intent = Intent(this, BluetoothService::class.java)
        bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE)
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                arrayOf(
                        Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION),
                PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_BLUETOOTH)
    }


    super.onStart()
}

override fun onStop() {
    unbindService(mConnection)
    super.onStop()
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_SELECT_DEVICE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

        connect.isEnabled = false

        mDevice = data?.getParcelableExtra(DEVICE)
        mSearch?.connect(mDevice!!, false, this)
    }
}
```